# How to return UIImage after it's loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, objective-c-blocks

I have a method similar to the one below:

```
- (UIImage*)getImage {
    return image;
}
```

Which returns an image loaded from a URL in another method. I only want the method above, however, to return once image is not longer 'nil' (i.e. once it has been loaded). What's the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Call (UIImage*)getImage inside your asynchronous method. Post your code for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)getImage:(void(^)(UIImage *image))callback{
    //Load image asynchronously
    if(callback){
       callback(image);
    }
}
```

I would like to use block to load an asynchronous image.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)getImage {
    //isLoaded is your own function
    if ([self isImageLoaded:image) {
          return image;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that (or at least you shouldn't); that's not how asynchronous works. You ask for the download to start and that's all; the method is over. Later, when the download has completed, the downloading code calls back into your code on the main thread and says "I have an image for you, take it."

Here's [the example code from my book](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m) showing a class designed (for iOS 7 only) for exactly this purpose. You call the method `download:completionHandler:` with the path of a URL and a block. Then you walk away and do nothing; you do not wait. You just go about your business, if any. When the download is finished, your block will be called and the image will be handed to you through that. Recognizing what image this is and dealing with it is up to you. The surrounding project shows an example (downloading images and popping them into a table view as they arrive).